# Python, помогите заменить список queueWaitingCustomers на очередь(Queue)

Tags: python

```
from time import sleep
from random import randint
from russian_names import RussianNames

customers = RussianNames(count=3, patronymic=False, transliterate=True, uppercase=True).get_batch()

haircutTimeMin = 30 # Минимальное время подстрижки 
haircutTimeMax = 60 # Максимальное время подстрижки 
AmountCustomersMin = 5 # Минимальное количество покупателей
AmountCustomersMax = 20 # Максимальное количество покупателей
lock = Lock()

class Customer: # Покупатель
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

class Barber: # Парикмахер
    barberWorkingEvent = Event()

    def barber_sleep(self):
        self.barberWorkingEvent.wait()

    def barber_wakeup(self):
        self.barberWorkingEvent.set() # True

    def barber_cuthair(self, customer):
        self.barberWorkingEvent.clear() # Парикмахер занят, False
        print("Customer {0} is having a haircut ".format(customer.name))
        randnomHairCutTime = randint(haircutTimeMin, haircutTimeMax)
        sleep(randnomHairCutTime)
        print('Customer {0} haircut is done'.format(customer.name))

class CoolBarberShop:

    queueWaitingCustomers = []

    def __init__(self, barber, numberOfSeats):
        self.barber = barber
        self.numberOfSeats = numberOfSeats
    
    def openBarberShop(self):
        print('Barber shop is open')
        workingThread = Thread(target = self.barberGoToWork)
        workingThread.start()
    
    def barberGoToWork(self):
        while True:
            lock.acquire()
            if len(self.queueWaitingCustomers) > 0:
                cust = self.queueWaitingCustomers[0]
                del self.queueWaitingCustomers[0]
                lock.release()
                barber.barber_cuthair(cust)
            else:
                lock.release()
                print ('Barber going to sleep')
                barber.barber_sleep()
                print ('Barber woke up')
    
    def customerEnter(self, customer):
        lock.acquire()
        print ('Customer {0} entered in the Barber shop and is looking for a free seat'.format(customer.name))
        if len(self.queueWaitingCustomers) == self.numberOfSeats:
            print ('Waiting room is full, customer {0} is leaving.'.format(customer.name))
            lock.release()
        else:
            print ('Customer {0} sat down in the waiting room'.format(customer.name))   
            self.queueWaitingCustomers.append(cust) 
            lock.release()
            barber.barber_wakeup()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    customers = []
    for i in range(100):
        i = (RussianNames(surname=False, patronymic=False).get_person())
        customers.append(Customer(i))
    barber = Barber()
    
    barberShop = CoolBarberShop(barber, numberOfSeats=3)
    barberShop.openBarberShop()
    while len(customers) > 0:
        cust = customers.pop()  
        #New customer enters the barbershop
        barberShop.customerEnter(cust)
        customerInterval = randint(AmountCustomersMin,AmountCustomersMax)
        sleep(customerInterval)
```

Comment: А в чём сложность? Заменяете извлечение из списка и добавление в список на аналогичные операции с очередью. Ничего сложного - один раз прочитать документацию по этим видам коллекций. Вернее даже по основным операциям с ними.

Comment: @CrazyElf Сложность возникает в функции barberGoToWork, я не понимаю как обратиться к первому элементу, а потом удалить её

Comment: А очередь вам какую всё-таки нужно использовать, конкретно? Стандартную `deque`? Там вроде всё это было легко.

Comment: @CrazyElf queue.Queue()

Comment: Ну вы доку пробовали читать? Метод `get` сделает сразу обе операции - возьмёт первый элемент из очереди и удалит его там. Это ещё проще, чем со списком работать, код короче будет https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html  А, и судя по доке, блокировки там все уже есть, сможете ещё и блокировки при работе с очередью из кода выкинуть